# Wordpress Pagination - max_num_pages = 0

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Wordpress ninjas...  I require some help regarding pagination.

I have the following code :

```
global $wp_query;
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, 
        array( 
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'paged' => $paged                                       
        )
 );
```

How come `$query->max_num_pages` returns `0` ?

And is there a way to alter the original archive query with the `$query->max_num_pages` ?

**[EDIT]**

In Addition to the above code I have the following

```
 $output = '<div class="download-attachments left_content_container"><ul>';

//this does not retrieve anything 
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );

// this does retrieve posts
$attachments = get_posts( $args );

// this block is only used for testing purposes.. 
// ie. it is not being executed because the query does not return anything, Whilst get_posts()    works 



 if( $query->have_posts() ){
         while( $query->have_posts() ){
             $query->the_post();
             echo the_ID();
         }
    }

 foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        setup_postdata($attachment);

        //get attachments metadata etc.
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
        $title = get_the_title( $attachment );
        $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
        $size = get_readable_size( filesize(get_attached_file( $attachment->ID )) );
        $icon =  get_icon_for_attachment( $attachment->ID );
        $mime = get_post_mime_type(  $attachment->ID );
        $date_added = $attachment->post_date;
        $filename = ( !$caption == '' ) ? $caption : $title ;
        $description =  ($attachment->post_content != '') ? '<span class="attachment-author"><span class="attachemnt-label">Added by: ' . $attachment->post_content . '</span></span>' : '';
        $output .= '<li class="'.$mime.'">
                    <img class="attachment-icon" src="'.$icon.'" alt="pdf"> 
                    <a href="'. home_url().'/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id='.$attachment->ID.'" class="attachment-link" title="'.$filename.'">'. $filename  .'</a>       '.$description.'
                    <span class="attachment-date"><span class="attachment-label">Date added:  </span>'.$date_added.'</span> 
                    <span class="attachment-size"><span class="attachment-label">Attachment size:  </span>'.$size.'</span></li>' ;


 }
 $output .= '</ul></div>';

 echo $output;


 echo '<div class="paging pull-left">';
        $paged = $wp_query->get(  'paged' );
        if ( ! $paged) {/* do nothing */ ;}
        else { bootstrap_pagination(); var_dump($wp_query->max_num_pages); // returns 0 }
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do this. Also, your code looks odd

Comment: Whats is odd about it ? I am trying to do this in the archive.php . Could it be that once you alter the main query, you need to reset it before being able to use `max_num_pages` ?

Comment: No, the problem is, your code is completely wrong. Will qiucly post code before going to bed :-)

Comment: Enlighten me, Sir, because I am completely new to the world of wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems here. You don't need to call the global `$wp_query` because you are not going to use it. Secondly, `array_merge` is totally out of place. This should not be used at all in this situation. Your code should look something like this

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged                                       
     )
 );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For more info on custom queries with `WP_Query` have a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: I updated the code as per your changes but max_num_pages still returns 0

Comment: Will see what I can do this afternoon when I get home. Posting from my phone right now

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I really don't understand how the same array argument works for `get_posts()` but not for `new WP_Query()`

Comment: Could this problem be the cause of the attachments not having a post parent ?  ie. I am trying to get a lists of attachments with the current category. when the url is `/category/member-resources/` the query will have a `category` set accordingly.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you need to display attachements from posts that belongs to the specific category being viewed when on the category page

Comment: No, the attachments do not belong to any post in particular, I want to get a list of attachments with a certain category according to the category page , but as for post parent, there isn't none. Is this possible ?

Comment: How do you mean these attachments don't have post parents. An attachment should belong to post, otherwise its status will show unattached, and therefor cannot have a category it belongs to. How was these images uploaded

Comment: I am using [this plugin][1] to allow me to add categories to media files.. Also the attachments are not images per se, but files such as pdfs, .doc etc 

 [1]: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-media-library-categories/

Comment: OK, to be honest, I haven't worked with this plugin and also don't know how it works, so I would not be able to help you with this

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. Your answer still helped me in a way. I went around it by creating pages for the mentioned categories and having the files attached to the posts.